# Tiltbrush Poly Fails to Work in Linux

Tags: linux, google-chrome, firefox, nixos

Poly animations from the [Tiltbrush section](https://poly.google.com/tiltbrush) fail to render for me in Linux (under either Chrome or Firefox): https://poly.google.com/tiltbrush

(Items from Poly's homepage do work, however).

I'm running NixOS with `nvidia` drivers.

How to troubleshoot?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is resolved when switching to `nvidiaBeta` drivers.